# Get added and deleted files from git diff output with HEAD

Tags: git, git-diff

I'm using git diff to get the differences between a commit and his parent for a specific file.
I'm using this command :

```
git diff parent-sha child-sha  -- file/to/path
```

Here is my problem : with this command I can get added, deleted and modified files for a specific commit. But when I try it on my current commit, I can only get modified/deleted files. I'm looking for a way to get deleted and added files for the current commit (comparing to his parent).

For instance here's my uncommitted changes :
[image]

If I run `git diff HEAD -- yarn.lock`

I get this

```
diff --git a/yarn.lock b/yarn.lock
deleted file mode 100644
index c06acb9..0000000
--- a/yarn.lock
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,10383 +0,0 @@
-# THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
-# yarn lockfile v1
-
-
-"7zip-bin@~4.1.0":
-  version "4.1.0"
-  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/7zip-bin/-/7zip-bin-4.1.0.tgz#33eff662a5c39c0c2061170cc003c5120743fff0"
-  integrity sha512-AsnBZN3a8/JcNt+KPkGGODaA4c7l3W5+WpeKgGSbstSLxqWtTXqd1ieJGBQ8IFCtRg8DmmKUcSkIkUc0A4p3YA==
-
-"@angular-devkit/architect@0.11.4":
-  version "0.11.4"
-  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@angular-devkit/architect/-/architect-0.11.4.tgz#f0cc3b4f1dd0128f6b41d3bb760bcf4c324cd063"
-  integrity sha512-2zi6S9tPlk52vyqN67IvFoeNgd0uxtrPlwl3TdvJ3wrH7sYGJnkQ+EzAE7cKUGWAV989BbNtx2YxhRDHnN21Fg==
```

But nothing on `git diff -- src/app/models/DiffFileInformation.ts`

Comment: Did you run `git diff HEAD^ HEAD`?

Comment: No, `diff` has the same behaviour with HEAD or any other ref. Maybe there *are* no deleted/added files here?

Comment: @ElpieKay (or even just `git diff HEAD^`)

Comment: Ok I think I misunderstood. I'm looking for a way to get differences between current commit and his parent. Maybe HEAD is not the current commit. I mean, if I delete a file right now and try to get the output of git diff (without committing changes), what should I run?

Comment: Yes I tried with both commands and I only get the modified files (I'll edit for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following 3 commands are not the same:

```
git diff
git diff HEAD
git diff HEAD^ HEAD
```

Suppose we have initialized a repo and made two commits and some extra uncommitted changes.

```
git init foo
cd foo
touch a.txt b.txt
git add .
git commit -m 'first commit'

echo hello >> a.txt
echo hello >> b.txt
git commit -m 'hello'

echo world >> a.txt
echo world >> b.txt
# stage a.txt and leave b.txt alone
git add a.txt
```

1. What does `git diff` return?

`git diff` compares the working tree and the index. The working tree has the modified version of `a.txt` and `b.txt`, and the index has only the modified version of `a.txt`. So the difference lies between the working tree's `b.txt` and the index's `b.txt`:

```
hello
world
```

VS

```
hello
```

`git diff` returns:

```
diff --git a/b.txt b/b.txt
index ce01362..94954ab 100644
--- a/b.txt
+++ b/b.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 hello
+world
```

2. What does `git diff HEAD` return?

It compares the files in the revision of `HEAD` with the files in the working tree. `a.txt` in `HEAD` is

```
hello
```

`a.txt` in the working tree is

```
hello
world
```

`b.txt` is the same with `a.txt`, so `git diff HEAD` returns:

```
diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
index ce01362..94954ab 100644
--- a/a.txt
+++ b/a.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 hello
+world
diff --git a/b.txt b/b.txt
index ce01362..94954ab 100644
--- a/b.txt
+++ b/b.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 hello
+world
```

3. What does `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` return?

It compares the files of the former revision with the files of the latter. In `HEAD^`, both `a.txt` and `b.txt` are empty. In `HEAD`, both are:

```
hello
```

So we get the output of `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` as:

```
diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
index e69de29..ce01362 100644
--- a/a.txt
+++ b/a.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+hello
diff --git a/b.txt b/b.txt
index e69de29..ce01362 100644
--- a/b.txt
+++ b/b.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+hello
```

If we swap `HEAD^` and `HEAD`, `git diff HEAD HEAD^` returns:

```
diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
index ce01362..e69de29 100644
--- a/a.txt
+++ b/a.txt
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-hello
diff --git a/b.txt b/b.txt
index ce01362..e69de29 100644
--- a/b.txt
+++ b/b.txt
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-hello
```

`HEAD` and `HEAD^` could be any commits reachable in the repository. Instead of swapping the revisions, we can also get the reversed diff with the option `-R`, `git diff -R HEAD^ HEAD`.

Not sure what your purpose exactly is. Maybe you can find the solution [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_description). More syntaxes of `git diff` are described.

Answer (score 4):

[ElpieKay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55454318/1256452) is correct (and I've upvoted it) but it might help you think about the problem if you take a step back and think about *commits* and how Git works.

Every commit holds several things, which we can break up into two major categories, *data* and *metadata*.  The *data* in a commit is the source code snapshot, and the *metadata* is extra information *about* the data, such as who made the snapshot, when, and so on (and importantly, the *parent hash ID* for the parent of this commit, or if it's a merge commit, all of its parent hash IDs, but I think you have that part well under control now).  Note that **everything inside the commit is frozen for all time**.  You cannot change any part of either the data *or* the metadata.

In fact, this is the case for *all* of Git's internal objects.  The hash ID of the Git object is a cryptographic checksum of the contents of that object.  This is great for archival—every commit, once made, can *never* be changed—but it's completely useless for getting any *new work* done.  To do new work, Git *must* provide some place(s) where files can be *modified*.

Every version control system has this problem, and in general, they all solve it the same way: the place where you work on your file is your *work-tree*.  Files in the work-tree are malleable.  Files in commits are not.  That means there's something fundamentally different about a work-tree than there is about a commit.  The work-tree could be a *proposed* commit, but it's still malleable, so it's not an *actual* commit.  (It doesn't have any metadata, either.)

So, in Git, a work-tree *does not have a hash ID*.  But for some reason, Git takes this even further.  Instead of just having the work-tree be the proposed next commit, Git adds a third entity, sitting *between* `HEAD`—the current commit—and the work-tree.  This third entity is called the *index*, or the *staging area*, or even sometimes the *cache*.  (You'll see all three names in Git documentation.  They all refer to the same thing.)  This index is where Git stores the proposed next commit.  Git then provides commands like `git add` that copy *from* the work-tree (where you have your files and can work on them) *to* the index (to update the proposed next commit).

This means `git diff` needs to be able to:

- compare commit vs commit
- compare commit vs index
- compare commit vs work-tree
- compare index vs work-tree

It provides four different ways to do this, depending on the arguments and `--cached` flag you pass *to* `git diff`:

- `git diff hash1 hash2` compares commit vs commit
- `git diff --cached hash` compares commit vs index
- `git diff hash` compares commit vs work-tree
- `git diff` compares index vs work-tree

Pick which one you want, add `-- <path>` to restrict the diff output, and you're all set.

Answer (score 1):

`git diff HEAD -- path` will show you your local modifications.

The file `src/app/models/DiffFileInformation.ts` is untracked and unstaged, so it won't appear in your diff.

To see it in the diff, you will need to stage it (add it) first.

Comment: There is no way I can get it with options?

Comment: No, not as far as I know. Basically, the diff of the file is the whole file itself. What exactly are you trying achieve? Stage something specific from the file?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that for new files added to git which are not staged yet, you could try:

```
git diff /dev/null "src/app/models/DiffFileInformation.ts"
```